# Campaign Tags ExactTarget

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way to extract the campaign tags out of Marketing Cloud? Through API or any other way?

I tried using REST API but it doesn't retrieve the campaign tags

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [Campaign Tags](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/campaigns/campaigns_tags/) are only used for the Campaign Planning Calendar.  Pretty sure they're not exposed to either of the APIs.

What I've done in the past is to utilize [Send Logging](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/) to *tag* campaigns with a keyword using AMPScript in the emails.  Once it's in the Send Log, you can relate it back to Send Jobs and Subscriber Activity using [Query Activities](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/).

Once the data is coalesced into a Data Extension, you can retrieve the rows via API ([DataExtensionObject[External/CustomerKey]](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/dataextensionobject/)).

Comment: Hello Adam, am a little new to this Send Logging thing ...can you please break it down a little bit for me?
I have created a Send Log DE .. what should I do next?

Comment: To enable it on a Triggered Send Definition or UI Send, just check the send logging checkbox on the detail page.  Any column in your Send Log DE that matches a personalization string or AMPScript variable will get recorded to the Send Log at send time.  For example, if you have a FirstName Profile Attribute or a @FirstName variable, the value would get recorded in the Send Log for that Subscriber at send time.